# Is statistical mechanics considered classical?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

If we divide mechanics into two categories- classical and quantum, which category does statistical mechanics fall in?

Answer (score 2):

Both, you can have energy distributions that are classical or quantum (or relativistic).